# angular show image with condition (checkbox)

Tags: image, angularjs, checkbox, show-hide

What I want to do here is that when my checkbox 'chBeamer' is checked the images of the beamers should appear if their beamername is not '/' (/ means that their is no beamer registrated)

## checkbox

```
<input ng-model="chBeamer" type="checkbox" id="chBeamer" name="chBeamer"/>
```

## ng-show

```
<div ng-show="chBeamer"><img id="beamer" src="../app/img/beamer.png"/></div>
```

I don't know how to start with this, I tried with a filter and condition (chBeamer !== '/') but this didn't work...

Answer (score 1):

From your post I can't quite understand where beamername is coming from, but you can do:

```
<div ng-show="chBeamer && beamername !== '/'">...</div>
```

But I feel like this is part of a bigger picture, e.g. there must be multiple items?  What does your underlying model look like?

Comment: Are you sure? I don't think evaluating an expression like that works.